# AJAX call not getting information on Intel XDK

Tags: android, angularjs, ajax, intel-xdk

I'm building an APK for the blood bank of my local city and i need to get the stock of blood by groups, i have some JSON that i test with Postman that woks but i need to add  them to my Intel XDK project. I have follow some examples with AJAX and HTTP but with no result.

```
 ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
 $("#ajax").click(function(){        
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://192.168.1.100/api/hospital/17659861-1',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Data RecibidaAPI: ' + data);
                    console.log(data.data[0].us_rut);
                    console.log(data.data[0].us_nombre);
                    console.log(data.data[0].us_telefono);
                    console.log(data.data[0].us_id_dispositivo);
                    console.log(data.data[0].us_grupo_sangre);
                }
            }).then(function (data) {
                console.log('Data RecibidaAPI: ' + data);
            });
        });

}
```

and also try

```
<div id="campa_de_sangre" class="upage-content vertical-col left hidden" ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
<p>hola</p>
            <h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>
            <p>Status : {{statuscode}}</p>
            <p>StatusText : {{statustext}}</p
            <p>{{content}}</p>
<script>
var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
app2.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "welcome.htm"
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      $scope.statuscode = response.status;
      $scope.statustext = response.statusText;   
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.content = "Something went wrong";

  });
});
</script>
</div>
```

where i could't even get the scope.satuscode to work.
I'm using Ionic as framework with AngularJS, if someone need extra info to helpmeet just ask and thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this FAQ on the Intel XDK web site > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/faqs/app-designer#ajax-jquery-one-fail

Answer (score 1):

If the call is being made successful but you're not getting your $scope to update try wrapping the values you need to update in $timeout .. you can use $scope.apply() but i believe $timeout to be the safer method

```
<div id="campa_de_sangre" class="upage-content vertical-col left hidden" ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
<p>hola</p>
            <h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>
            <p>Status : {{statuscode}}</p>
            <p>StatusText : {{statustext}}</p
            <p>{{content}}</p>
<script>
var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);
app2.controller('myCtrl2', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "welcome.htm"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            $scope.statuscode = response.status;
            $scope.statustext = response.statusText;
        }, 0)
    }, function myError(response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
        }, 0)

    });
});
</script>
</div>
```